# Problem handling file I/O with libevent2

Tags: linux, file, libevent

I worked with libevent2 for some time, but usually I used it to handle network I/O (using sockets). Now I need to read many different files so I also wanted to use it. I created this code:

```
int file = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
struct event *ev_file_read = event_new(ev_base, file, EV_READ | EV_PERSIST, read_file, NULL);

if(event_add(ev_file_read, NULL))
        error("adding file event");
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get this message when trying to add event:

> [warn] Epoll ADD(1) on fd 7 failed.  Old events were 0; read change was 1 (add); write change was 0 (none): Operation not permitted
>   adding file event: Operation not permitted

The file exists and has rights to read/write.

Anyone has any idea how to handle file IO using libevent? I thought also about bufferred events, but in API there's only function bufferevent_socket_new() which doesn't apply here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed libevent to read many files regarding priorities. The problem was in epoll not in libevent. Epoll doesn't support regular Unix files.

To solve it I forced libevent not to use epoll:

```
    struct event_config *cfg = event_config_new();

event_config_avoid_method(cfg, "epoll");

ev_base = event_base_new_with_config(cfg);  
    event_config_free(cfg);
```

Next method on the preference list was poll, which fully support files just as I wanted to.

Thank you all for answers.

Comment: oh god, I wasted so much time trying to figure this out. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Makes no sense to register regular file descriptors with `libevent`. [File descriptors associated with regular files shall always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/FD_SET.html)

Comment: oh it makes a lot of sense to want such a thing, believe me. and you can have it by adding one level of indirection, see below (or above).

Comment: That has little to do with a regular file descriptor.

Comment: directly it has nothing to do, I won't dare to say the opposite; but you can still manage to integrate disk i/o within an existent event loop and this may eliminate some complexity, decrease response times, etc (e.g. the case of a static, readonly http file service)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do async disk i/o you may want to check the aio_* family (see man (3) aio_read). it's POSIX.1-2001 and available on linux and bsd (at least).

for integrating aio operations with libevent, see [libevent aio patch](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2014953&group_id=50884&atid=461324) and a [related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173576/revisiting-how-do-you-use-aio-and-epoll-together) that mention using signalfd(2) to route the aio signal events to a file descriptor that can be used with various fd event polling implementations (so implicitly with libevent loop).

EDIT: libevent also has signal handling support (totally forgot about that) so you can try and register/handle the aio signals directlry with/from libevent loop. I'd personally go and try the libevent patch first if your development rules allows you to.